# got ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error for my website

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

well I didn't do anything I mean any changes to my website. yesterday when I try to open my website which is https://www.maket.ir I got This site can’t be reached maket.ir’s server IP address could not be found. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.
I have no idea what to look and what to do. I just check my public directory and everything is fine but I keep getting this page. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain maket.ir [expired on the 8th September 2019](http://whois.nic.ir/?name=maket.ir). You need to renew the domain with the domain registrar, [ccTLD Registry of Iran](https://www.nic.ir/). To prevent the problem in future, you should renew the domain before the expiry date.

Comment: Oh.. so that's my cousin's fault :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that the domain name could not be resolved. I looked at this with nslookup, and I get NXDOMAIN back. Could you check the status of your doamin name with your DNS registrar?

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately I don't know how to to this can you please guide me how to to this?

Comment: We need more information for this. How did you get that domain name? If you are not running the authoritative DNS server for this domain, then this is an administrative problem. Try to look for a domain name registration form.